# External drive: Error when getting information for file"/myfile": Structure needs cleaning. Actually an alignment issue

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I have seen a lot of these errors posted here, and fsck and e2fsck are not fixing the problem. I have determined the partition is offset by 3072 bytes... and while there are many answers to this issue, I have not backup the drive in question recently, and I really need some assurance and hand holding before I give anything a try. Mind helping me out?

I have a 8tb external drive. I can access all folders on the drive except for one folder which has one file in question that is preventing the folder from being opened, and the contents of all other folders are correct and have no errors. When I try to access the specific folder folder in question I get this error:

```
 Error when getting information for file"/myfile": Structure needs cleaning
```

Notice how this is due to one file? This file should be about 1.3-1.5gbs. I figured it was a superblock issue, based on a million google hits indicating this was my situation. So I did the following:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

/dev/sde is the disk in question, specifically I get this error, which shows up in red when running the above command:

```
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

This makes me think its a sector issue and not a superblock? PS, here is the info for this drive:

```
Disk /dev/sde: 7.3 TiB, 8001563221504 bytes, 15628053167 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1DC5927B-46DC-487D-865D-4635BEFAD0A6

Device      Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sde1      34      262177      262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sde2  264192 15628052479 15627788288  7.3T Linux filesystem
```

To address the potential superblock issue I got a list of my super blocks and noted the output indicating the alignment offset.

```
  sudo mke2fs -n /dev/sde1

mke2fs 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
/dev/sde1 alignment is offset by 3072 bytes.
This may result in very poor performance, (re)-partitioning suggested.
Creating filesystem with 131072 1k blocks and 32768 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 36025590-1af9-46cf-a895-5dec7484c9bf
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    8193, 24577, 40961, 57345, 73729
```

What is the best way to re-partition to reduce my chances of losing data? And why has Microsoft reserved this partition? This drive was bought new and has never been plugged into a windows machine in  it's existence.

Finally, I have a second identical drive that I use to backup the drive in question (I just haven't backup it up in the last two weeks). I don't have a Microsoft reserved partition on the other drive. Could this be related to the problem?

Many, many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Folks, I have no idea why this worked, but it did. I spent my morning transferring and backing up as much of the data on the drive in question as I could, unmounted it, opened the disk editor on ubunutu, tried to repair the partition using the repair option, I received an error saying it couldn't be done, so I ran the partition check, and suddenly ... the partition was fine. In disbelief I opened the drive and folder in question and it was fine as if this whole day was just a bad dream.